# Migrating exchange calendar entries from company exchange to personal exchange

Tags: exchange

How can I migrate Exchance calendar entries from my company exchange account to my own personal exchange account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also drag and drop those calendar entries by opening both calendars so you can see them in a side-by-side view.

Simply hold the control button on the company calendar entry as you drag it over to your personal calendar. If you dont hold the control button you will remove the entry from the company calendar.

Comment: +1 for remembering Windows drag & drop, something my wife always reminds me of. "power user - meh."

Answer (score 3):

Export your company Exchange calendar to a new PST file.  Take that PST file home and import the PST calendar entries into your personal exchange calendar.

**Exporting** (Outlook 2003):
Highlight your company Exchange calendar --> File --> Import and Export --> Export to a File --> Next --> Personal Folders File (.pst) --> Continue following the wizard

**Importing** (Outlook 2003):
Highlight your personal Exchange calendar --> File --> Import and Export --> Import from another program or file --> Next --> Personal Folders File (.pst) --> Continue following the wizard (When you get to it, select "import items into the same folder in:" and choose your personal Exchange mailbox)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to export just calendar events from one account and then import them into another.  I believe you will need to highlight the calendar item when exporting to just get those items.